# multinom() clustered standard error

Tags: multinomial-logit

I am attempting to identify the appropriate code for calculating clustered standard errors following the execution of a regression using the multinom() function.

I attempted the following code, but consistently encountered an error:

> ## Calculate the cluster-robust variance-covariance matrix
>
> vcov_clustered <- vcovCL(reg1, cluster = mtcars$cyl)
> Error in UseMethod("estfun") :
> no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('multinom', 'nnet')"